# Changing the IP of a network adapter without admin rights as the restricted user

Tags: networking, ip, administrator, adapter, non-admin

I’m a member of a company where computers are lend to workers without admin rights. Due to my specific hiring situation, despite being part of an area where "we" don't require changing IP functions, i actually need to be able to constantly change IP in order to access the web interfaces of the monitoring equipment like HVAC communication interfaces or controllers, so they are able to communicate freely with the automation servers our BMS has.

The IT department here works only in office hours but, we are required to be at weekends or nights depending on the shift we cover also we need to be connected to a specific local network where they can actually perform those changes using the credentials they have. Often this equipment are often installed outside the reach of that network making the process annoying for both parts.

Is there a way to bypass admin rights in order to be able to have full control of my IP so I can connect freely to this equipment and not depend on them? I cannot be prommoted to admin nor ask for the rights for Network IP changing.

Doesn't matter if it requires hardware as long it doesn't require another PC or disassembling the one they gave to me to modify the already existing adapter or any new one added by usb (we have open usb, not sure if we can bot from them thought).

Comment: You do know that you can configure you laptop to have more than one ip address.

Comment: You probably should get the people who hired you to speak to IT and have you be made a local admin on your computer so you can do your job

Comment: well i'm aware of having 1 per adapter, not sure if you can have more on just 1 adapter, aside from wifi wich is sadly useless for this i only have 1 ethernet adapter

Comment: Also IT can take years to make "big" changes, one of my coworkwers with specific requirments has been on a 3 month wait to just install 1 program